# want to show pin on leaflet map using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I am trying to create a map using React JS and a leaflet

but the problem is I am not able to map position on the map

here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  MapContainer,
  TileLayer,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  ZoomControl,
} from 'react-leaflet';
import { FullscreenControl } from 'react-leaflet-fullscreen';
import './MapComponent.css'; 
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';


const MapComponent=()=>{
 const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState('51.505');
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState('-0.09');
  const [position, setPosition] = useState([
    parseFloat(latitude),
    parseFloat(longitude),
  ]); 

const handleLatitudeChange = (e) => {
    setLatitude(e.target.value);
    setPosition([parseFloat(e.target.value), position[1]]);
  };

  const handleLongitudeChange = (e) => {
    setLongitude(e.target.value);
    setPosition([position[0], parseFloat(e.target.value)]);
  };

  const handleMapClick = (e) => {
    const { lat, lng } = e.target.value;
    setPosition([lat, lng]);
    setLatitude(lat.toString());
    setLongitude(lng.toString());
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setLatitude('');
    setLongitude('');
    setPosition([51.505, -0.09]); 
  };

const handleSubmit = () => {
      const lat = parseFloat(latitude);
      const lon = parseFloat(longitude);
         if (!isNaN(lat) && !isNaN(lon)) {
           setPosition([lat, lon]);
         }
    console.log(setPosition);
    console.log('Latitude:', latitude);
    console.log('Longitude:', longitude);
  };

  const clearInputs = () => {
    setLatitude('');
    setLongitude('');
  };

return (
 <div className="map-container">
      <MapContainer className="map" center={position} zoom={13} onClick={handleMapClick} zoomControl={false} fullscreenControl={true}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            Latitude: {latitude} <br />
            Longitude: {longitude}
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
        <ZoomControl position="bottomright" />
        <FullscreenControl position="topright" />
      </MapContainer>
      <div className="controls">
        <div>
          Latitude:
          <input type="text" value={latitude} onChange={handleLatitudeChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          Longitude:
          <input type="text" value={longitude} onChange={handleLongitudeChange} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
          <button onClick={handleClear}>Clear</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
)
}
```

but when I enter the lat and long from the textbox and click on the submit button map is not show me the pin where I want to show it

can someone help me with this so that when ever I put the value inside the lat and long input and enter then it shows on the map?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useMapEvents` hook from React Leaflet to attach event listeners to the map and trigger the `flyto` function from the Leaflet library within the event listener to animate the map view based on user interactions or map changes. like this:

```
  const map = useMapEvents({});
  map.flyTo([lat, lon]);
```